# Not getting the Value from Firebase Database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

As you see at the code I used `getValue()` to get a value from my database. But when I would like to store that Value at a `private static int` variable (called "version") it's like nothing happened.

```
mDataBaseVersion =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(link).getReference().getRef().child("version/number");

    mDataBaseVersion.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

               setVersion((Integer) dataSnapshot.getValue());

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error at version check",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

The "version" setter:

```
 public void setVersion(int ver)
{
    version=ver;
}
```

And the part of the JSON what i should reach:

```
 {
"version" : {
      "number" : 2
      }
}
```

I've tried to solve the problem by myself, but i really cannot understand what is going on.

I am using the same structure to get the other elements from my DB (and that's working).

Do someone know why is it happening?

Comment: Please post the actual code, not a picture of it. Also, please give us [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem along with your expectation.

Comment: I've edited the post. I hope that helps understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference versionRef = rootRef.child("version");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        Integer number = dataSnapshot.child("number").getValue(Integer.class);
        Log.d("TAG", number);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
versionRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: Thank you! That helped me a lot.